# pylint W0221 arguments-differ

Tags: python, pylint

Running into **W0221** `arguments-differ` warning from pylint while writing a custom python [codec](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html?highlight=codec#module-codecs).

```
class mycodec(codecs.Codec):
    def encode(self, inp, errors='strict'):
        pass
```

pylint is complaining about the declaration of `def encode()`. I know I can silence the warning, but this seems like a pretty simple case of a bug in pylint, no?

```
> pylint --version
pylint 2.4.2
astroid 2.3.1
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: It seems that it is a bug and the issue is still open. Check [this](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1553)